# URL-based Goal doesn't get reached in Google Analytics despite the same URL-based PageView being registered correctly.

Tags: google-analytics

I've got a multi-stage online questionnaire form, and I use a `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/Form_Stage_XX'])` code to register form's stages destinations (the "XX"s stand for actual stage numbers).

I also set up the URL-destination Goals based on pages `/Form_Stage_XX` (same as in _gaq.push).

Now in the `Site content -> Pages` report I can see the visits of `/Form_Stage_XX` registered as expected, but the related Goals won't get reached.

Any ideas why is this?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please do check your goals configuration in the **Profile Settings - > Goals** Page to see if the URL is set to the same as **/Form_Stage_XX** and also if the Match Type is set to **Exact Match**. I would also recommend using the Match Type: **Regular Expression** with **.*\Form_Stage_XX** as the parameter.

You should be able to see if your goals are beign tracked as expected in the **Conversions - > Goals** Report.

One more thing is that form goals are usually better tracked as a Funnel Conversion, so you can track the flow from each step and thus visualize where visitors are leaving your form.

You can find more information in this great [video lesson](http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/v5/goals_v20_ad1/), made by Google